# creating unlimited sub domains through api from premium DNS hosting provider

Tags: dns, automation, subdomain, dyndns

I already found one post  [DNS provider for unlimited subdomains with api access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779097/dns-provider-for-unlimited-subdomains-with-api-access) about subdomain creation through api. But the above post doesn't solve my query

**what's my requirement is**

1) looking for premium dns hosting provider which enables me to create unlimited sub domains from my application using their api

2) currently i am having multiple dedicated server's from one vendor and bought domain name from another  vendor. But my current domain registrar provides premium dns hosting. It enables me to create unlimited sub domains manually without api access. So i am looking for third party premium dns hosting provider with api access for sub domain creation.

**Note:**

currently i had no plan to run my own dns server through bind

**For clarity visit**

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/45284/creating-unlimited-sub-domains-programmatically-through-api

Answer (score 0):

I know Dreamhost offers unlimited subdomains and they also have an API to create new DNS records (among several other things)... Here's the wiki for creating DNS records (like subdomains, etc): http://wiki.dreamhost.com/API/Dns_commands... Or here's the main API page: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/API#List_of_API_Modules

Comment: currently dream host dedicated servers are costly than my current provider and another problem is i am having multiple dedicated servers. so whether dream host will provide premium dns hosting as a service?